# Data Response Not able to map in the react router

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-router

I have created a e Commerce App in react. As you can see from the screenshot below, that when I click on the Apparels->Girls->Shoes , the data is not displayed in the screen.

[image]

So first, in the index.js file, I have set the BrowserRouter and created a component Main which holds all my other components.

index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Main from "./Main";
import "./index.css";
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import {Route, NavLink, BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom';

ReactDOM.render((


  <BrowserRouter>
   <Main/>
   </BrowserRouter>



)

 , 
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

After this I have created Main.js, where I have created components for Navigation and PLPMenu( which should display after clicking on the Girls->Shoes). Also in the Main.js, I have set the switch and Route paths

Main.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import Navigation from "./components/topNavigation";
import Footer from "./components/Footer";
import Banner from "./components/Banner";
import PLPMenu from "./components/PLPMenu";
import PDP from "./components/PDP";
import Home from "./components/Home";





class Main extends Component {


  render() {


    return (
      <div>


        <Navigation />

        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route path="Apparel/Girls/:id" component={PLPMenu}/>
          <Route path="/PDP" component={PDP} />
          <Route path="/Banner" component={Banner} />
          <Route path="/Footer" component={Footer} />
        </Switch>


      </div>

    )

  }


}

export default Main;
```

In the topNavigation.js, I'm displaying the first level of categories like Apparel, Electronics, Grocery etc. Also, I have created, a component SubMenu for displaying the second level of categories like Girls, Boys, Women etc.

topNavigation.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import SubMenu from './subMenu';



class Navigation extends Component {

  state = {
    mainCategory: []
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('http://localhost:3030/topCategory')
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res.data.express);
        this.setState({
          mainCategory: res.data.express.catalogGroupView
        })
      })
  }



  render() {

    const { mainCategory } = this.state;
    return mainCategory.map(navList => {
      return (

        <ul className="header">
          <li key={navList.uniqueID}>
            <a className="dropbtn ">{navList.name} </a>
              <ul className="dropdown-content">
                <SubMenu below={navList.catalogGroupView} />
              </ul>


          </li>
        </ul>

      )

    })

  }


}

export default Navigation;
```

subMenu.js

```
In the submenu.js, I have created one more component SubListMenu for displaying the inner categories like Shoes, Pants, Skirts, Tops etc.

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import SubListMenu from './subListMenu';


class SubMenu extends Component {
    render() {
        const { below } = this.props;
        return below.map(sub => {

            return (

                <React.Fragment>

                    <li key={sub.uniqueID}>

                        <a>{sub.name}</a>

                        {
                            <ul className="sub-menu">
                                {sub.catalogGroupView !== undefined && <SubListMenu id={sub.uniqueID} subBelow={sub.catalogGroupView} />}
                            </ul>


                        }

                    </li>

                </React.Fragment>

            )
        })

    }

}

export default SubMenu;
```

subListMenu.js

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';

    class SubListMenu extends Component {
      render() {
        const { subBelow, id } = this.props;
       console.log(subBelow)
        return(
           <React.Fragment>
               {subBelow && subBelow.map(subl => {
                 return (
                    <li key={subl.uniqueID}><Link to = {`Apparel/Girls/${subl.name}/${ subl.uniqueID }`}>{subl.name}</Link></li>

                 )
              })
            }
           </React.Fragment>
        )        
       } 
     }

    export default SubListMenu;
```

As you can see from my subListMenu.js code, that I have set the Link to PLPMenu.js. But in my case it's not happening. Also, the part Apparel/Girls in the Link, I have hard coded which i'm not able to make it dynamic.

PLPMenu.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';


import axios from 'axios';

class PLPMenu extends Component {

  state = {
    shoeCategory: []
  }



  componentDidMount() {
    let pathname= this.props.match.params.id
console.log(pathname)


  axios.get(`http://localhost:3030/${pathname}`)
    .then(res => (res.json()))
    .then(data => {
     this.setState({
          shoeCategory: data.express.catalogEntryView
     })
  });
}



  render() {
    const { shoeCategory } = this.state;

    const picUrl = 'https://149.129.128.3:8443'

    return (

      <div>
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row">
            {

              shoeCategory && shoeCategory.map(shoeList => (

                <div className="col-md-4">

                  <h2 key={shoeList.uniqueID}></h2>


                  <img src={picUrl + shoeList.thumbnail} />
                  <Link to="/PDP"><p className="pdp">{shoeList.name}</p></Link>
                  <p>Price : {shoeList.price[0].value} {shoeList.price[0].currency}</p>


                </div>

              ))
            }
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>




    )

  }

}

export default PLPMenu;
```

For fetching the data, I have used a node server.

server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const Client = require('node-rest-client').Client;//import it here
const app = express();

app.use(cors());





app.get('/topCategory', (req, res) => {

    var client = new Client();

    // direct way
    client.get("http://149.129.128.3:3737/search/resources/store/1/categoryview/@top?depthAndLimit=-1,-1,-1,-1", (data, response) => {
     res.send({ express: data });
    });
 });

 app.get('/GirlShoeCategory', (req, res) => {

    var client = new Client();

    // direct way
    client.get("http://149.129.128.3:3737/search/resources/store/1/productview/byCategory/10015", (data, response) => {
     res.send({ express: data });
    });
 });



const port = 3030;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server running on port${port}`));
```

I don't know where my code is getting wrong. Maybe I feel that from the node server, there is a mismatch with the reactjs routes, for which only in the url, it's displaying the link but not the contents. Can someone please give me an insight on this. My console browser window:

[image]

Comment: console `this.props` check id is exist or not in ` subListMenu.js`

Comment: How are you sending props to SubListMenu.js?

Comment: It's showing as undefined

Comment: @AkshayAggarwal this.props.id is what I'm using. If I use only this.props this is the response which it shows in the console.
identifier: "Girls Shoes"
name: "Shoes"
parentCatalogGroupID: (2) ["10001_5", "10502_5"]
resourceId: "http://149.129.128.3:3737/search/resources/store/1/categoryview/byId/10015"
shortDescription: "Shoes"
storeID: "10501"
uniqueID: "10015"
__proto__: Object

Comment: Wait I'm editing my question......Then you will get the whole picture

Comment: @ShaswatiBhattacharyya See here in this.props you do not have ID and you are trying to access it that is why undefined.

Comment: For your components that only render and don't maintain state, why don't you use a functional component?

Comment: I have posted everything @AkshayAggarwal. Can you please help me

Comment: @ShaswatiBhattacharyya  Please post the contents of subBelow and this.props.

Comment: subBelow contents are in subListMenu.js. I'm passing that as props.You can check that in my question. I have send all the codes.

Comment: @AkshayAggarwal Did you got the {subBelow}. I'm passing that one in subListMenu.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for this issue

```
In the PLPMenu.js page, I'm trying to fetch the data. But all I'm getting is this undefined.

componentDidMount() {
let pathname= this.props.match.params.id

console.log(this.props.match.params.id)

axios.get(`http://localhost:3030/${pathname}`)
 .then(res => {return res.json();})
 .then(data => {
  this.setState({
      shoeCategory: data.express.catalogEntryView
  })
});
}
```

try this it will solve undefined issue.

Comment: Now the Id is coming is coming in the url but in the console, it's showing undefined. Shall I edit my question as to what I have done till now

Comment: in my console it is showing as   

(4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {identifier: "Girls Shoes", fullImage: "/wcsstore/ExtendedSitesCatalogAssetStore/images/catalog/apparel/girls/category/catr_gsh_shoes.png", thumbnail: "/wcsstore/ExtendedSitesCatalogAssetStore/images/catalog/apparel/girls/category/catr_gsh_shoes.png", storeID: "10501", name: "Shoes", …}
undefined

Comment: @ShaswatiBhattacharyya yes please update the question

Comment: Please provide the code for SublistMenu.js @ShaswatiBhattacharyya

Comment: @ShaswatiBhattacharyya okay you are getting undefined because there is not such thing as uniqueId in our props . this.props contains an array and you are assigning that array to subBelow look at this line " <li key={subl.uniqueID}><Link to = {`Apparel/Girls/${ subl.uniqueID }`}>{subl.name}</Link></li>" , this is actually the correct way to access that is why you getting undefined in console but getting id in path.

Comment: In the PLP page, I need to display on basis of ID...Can you please help me on this

Comment: by clicking on that link does it takes you to where you want to go? you are getting id in the link right?

Comment: It displays as blank....Only in the url I'm getting the link. in the console browser window, I'm getting the response. The undefined is gone now

Comment: are you getting the response in PLPmenu? and also can please show me contents of this.props in PLPmenu?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180849/discussion-between-shaswati-bhattacharyya-and-akshay-aggarwal).

Comment: I'm not getting any response in PLPMenu. It's showing in subListMenu. When I put console.log(this.props) in PLPMenu, nothing appears. I have again updated my question and attached the screenshots.

Comment: i have uploaded my code in git and shared you the link  https://github.com/shaswati007/reactonline

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180874/discussion-between-shaswati-bhattacharyya-and-akshay-aggarwal).

Comment: You need to make me contributor in repo so I can push the code...my username is akshay1293. @ShaswatiBhattacharyya

Comment: I have send you the request......Also have made some changes in the code. Will you review it.

Comment: I have pushed the code to the repo I think it solved the problem. You have to go on your own from now...good luck ;-) .... and one more thing whatever changes you have made today... please remove them and take pull then test and start working again

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have to take `id` from `subBelow` instead `this.props.id`.

so change the code like this.

```
<li key={subl.uniqueID}><Link to = {`Apparel/Girls/${ subl.uniqueID }`}>{subl.name}</Link></li>
```

Comment: id is showing in the url...but in the console, it's showing undefined in the console

Comment: After, making the changes in the code, still after clicking on the Shoe Link, it's showing blank screen

Comment: what you mean by ?

Comment: Can you please help me a little. I have made the changes in the code and updated my question

Comment: really it's confusing Shaswati, why can't you ask as new question.

Comment: don't edit question may times, finally accepted ans and your question will not match, if possible ask as new question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180873/discussion-between-shaswati-bhattacharyya-and-lsa4299).

Answer (score 1):

The reason you get undefined in URL bar because you are not passing the unique id from SubMenu down to SubListMenu component.

What you need to do is

SubMenu.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import SubListMenu from './subListMenu';


class SubMenu extends Component {
    render() {
        const { below } = this.props;
        return below.map(sub => {

            return (

                <React.Fragment>

                    <li key={sub.uniqueID}>

                        <a>{sub.name}</a>

                        {
                            <ul className="sub-menu">
                                {sub.catalogGroupView !== undefined && <SubListMenu id={sub.uniqueID} subBelow={sub.catalogGroupView} />}
                            </ul>


                        }

                    </li>

                </React.Fragment>

            )
        })

    }

}

export default SubMenu;
```

SubListMenus.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';

class SubListMenu extends Component {
  render() {
    const { subBelow, id } = this.props;
    console.log(subBelow)
    return(
       <React.Fragment>
           {subBelow && subBelow.map(subl => {
             return (
               <li key={subl.uniqueID}><Link to = {`Apparel/Girls/${ id }`}>{subl.name}</Link></li>
             )
          })
        }
       </React.Fragment>
    )        
   } 
 }

export default SubListMenu;
```

Regarding below issue You need to do res.json() and in next .then get the data

```
 In the PLPMenu.js page, I'm trying to fetch the data. But all I'm getting is this undefined.
```

Do this

```
componentDidMount() {
    let pathname= this.props.match.params.id

    console.log(this.props.match.params.id)

  axios.get(`http://localhost:3030/${pathname}`)
    .then(res => (res.json()))
    .then(data => {
     this.setState({
          shoeCategory: data.express.catalogEntryView
     })
  });
}
```

Edit:

Add below condition in PLPMenu component

```
{shoeCategory && shoeCategory.map(shoeList => (
```

Comment: in the console browser window, it's showing as undefined

Comment: sorry I'm not getting it. Can you point me to the console.log line in your code?

Comment: Sorry my bad. I got your issue now. I updated my answer. Please give a try

Comment: undefined error has gone and response is showing in browser window....But, when I click on Girls-> Shoes, it's shows blank screen.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180872/discussion-between-shaswati-bhattacharyya-and-think-twice).